# Sequelize.js how to map a varbinary type from MySQL

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I am trying to use Sequelize.js to map all of the columns in my MySQL table.

The mysql table "User" has a Password column as type `varbinary(50)`.

Does Sequelize.js support mapping for a varbinary type? I did not see such an option in the [Sequelize docs](http://www.sequelizejs.com/), is there another way I can map it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The built-in types in sequelize just maps to strings, so intead of:

```
User = sequelize.define('user', {
  Password: Sequelize.STRING
});
```

You can write your own string like this:

```
User = sequelize.define('user', {
  Password: 'VARBINARY(50)'
});
```

This is only necessary if you want sequelize to create your table for you (`sequelize.sync()`), if you are using pre-created tables it does not matter what you write as the type. The only exception to this is if you are using the `Sequelize.BOOLEAN` type, which converts 0 and 1 to their boolean value.