# Insert byte array into MySQL VARBINARY column with Sequelize

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I have a byte array that I'm trying to insert into a `VARBINARY` column with Sequelize. I've defined the column based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13915464/1107110) like so:

```
MyTable = sequelize.define('my_table', {
  my_column: 'VARBINARY(16)'
});
```

I've tried the following to insert:

```
MyTable.create({
  my_column: myByteArray
});
```

But I just end up with each byte of the array as a separate value in the insert statement:

```
INSERT INTO `my_table` (`my_column`) VALUES (0,-1,-1,-64,-88,43,1);
```

So what's the proper way to go about inserting a byte array into MySQL as `VARBINARY` using Sequelize?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass it as a [`Buffer`](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html):

```
MyTable.create({
  my_column: Buffer.from(myByteArray)
});
```